# How do I pass an attribute to a core-ajax in an element definition?

Tags: ajax, polymer

I am creating an element, which takes one parameter: userid.
Inside the component's template I have a core-ajax tag which needs to pass that attribute as a parameter.

I am doing it like this:

```
<template attributes="userid">
    <core-ajax
        auto
        url="../../ajax/gettoday.php" 
        handleAs="json" 
        method="post" 
        params='{"userid": "{{userid}}"}'
        response="{{today}}"></core-ajax>
        ...
</template>
```

Is it supposed to accept the attribute inside the params string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `attributes="userid"` needs to be on the `<polymer-element>`, not the element's `<template>`. Nothing should go on the topmost `<template>`.

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="userid">
```

This works for me: http://jsbin.com/fihuyuga/1/edit